# Is it possible to fill out a form and have it submit multiple identical entries with the exception of one field? More details in post, thanks!

Tags: custom-form, multiple-values

I have a SharePoint form and list. Here are the fields for the list:

- Trip Title
- Traveler
- Cost
- Funding Type
- Location

There are more fields but we will stop there for the sake of simplicity.

Here is what I want - Each field has one form field with the exception of "traveler" which has multiple. I want to make it so if someone fills out the form (one time) but selects two travelers, two entries will be submitted into the sharepoint list. Both entries have identical field values except for the "Traveler" field which is the only field keeping the newly added entries from being identical.

I tried to create a form that has "repeating fields" but all that really does is duplicate each field. If I could somehow only duplicate the "travelers" field but have the other fields remain as singles that would be awesome.

Is this possible? And if not and you are able to get the idea of what I am trying to do, any other methods you think may work?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need to create one to many relation in your list. Travelers name will be stored in a separate list and other information will be in main list. Create a mapping column in Travelers list and map it with your main list.

There is another approach: Create a multi lookup field type and it will store all the travelers detail with some delimiter in your same list. Refer http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/multiple-column-lookup-field-for-sharepoint/